# asp.net web api - json serialization of interface member resulting in mystifying error

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm using ASP.NET Web API and I'm trying to return an instance of a class that looks like this:

```
public class Whatever
{
  public int MyInt {get; set;}
  public IFoo MyFoo {get; set;}
}
```

When this instance gets serialized to JSON, the `IFoo` member (which could be an instance of any of a number of classes implementing `IFoo`) gets serialized oddly. The property name is written, but its value is a huge chunk of HTML containing an error message like this:

```
You must write an attribute 'type'='object' after writing the attribute with local name '__type'.
```

Is this the framework telling me that it doesn't know how to serialize an instance cast as an interface? Or something else?

Comment: A downvote with no explanation serves no purpose.

Comment: My experiments suggest that the problem is that the member is expressed as an interface. When expressed as concrete type, the error disappears. But there are scenarios where I need to be able to assign multiple types to the same member of the class. What do I do then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this error occurs whenever the framework tries to serialize a member whose type is an interface. Apart from changing the member so that its type is concrete, I can find no other way around this problem.

Comment: Yes, you cannot serialize an interface. You have to provide KnownTypes and all that. avoid exposing interfaces in your Web API.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've never come across the KnownTypes thing before. As you say, it's probably not great design to have an interface member in a view model class anyway.